# Need a way for player to move towards the direction the camera is pointing. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, 3d

I am a beginner programmer who has begun practicing by doing some 3rd person movement scripts. For the camera, I used Cinemachine's Free Look camera but I have a problem. The player has a set-forward direction but I would like that direction to change to wherever the player is facing. I have looked up a few different things but none of them have worked in my code. Any help would be appreciated. C#. (Sorry not all code would go in.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CapsuleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool BeanOnTheGround = true;

    private void start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;


        transform.Translate(horizontal, 0, vertical);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && BeanOnTheGround) {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 5, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
            BeanOnTheGround = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            BeanOnTheGround = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple questions? 1.- do you try to set the rotataion somewhere in the shown script??? 2.- The gameObject you want to set the rotation to is the one that has the `CapsuleMovement` attached, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

I would try:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward, Camera.main.transform.up);
```

For the transform of the gameObject you want to set the rotation to.
For example, the gameObject with this script attached will face to the forward of the main camera at the `Start` time.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LookToCamForward : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward, Camera.main.transform.up);
    }
}
```